# Laravel : Set Timestamp return only custom date

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-5

In my app I just set `timezone` as `UTC` when I return response I got date  format as `UTC`.

```
    "created_at": {
        "date": "2018-05-18 15:17:37.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "date": "2018-06-08 05:49:05.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    }
```

But I only need `updated_at : 2018-06-08 05:49:05`, I do not need `timzone type, timezone`..
Expected :

```
    "country"   : "United States Of America",
    "region"    : "Northeast",
    "updated_at": "2018-06-08 05:49:05"
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: write object like `$object->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` - you will get date only

Comment: @dekts return a raw data.

Comment: Are you using **protected $dates** in your Model???

Comment: @Davit yes.Is anything wrong in that case ? `protected $casts = [ 'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d'];`

Comment: when you using **protected $dates** laravel it automatically wrap Carbon object all columns in $dates property

Comment: Yup so I gt `updated_at": "2018-06-08 08:34:02` instead of carbon object.right ?

Comment: If you want i can add post

Comment: @Davit yes please add am confuse.It ll help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172745/discussion-between-davit-and-javed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

You can do this by using an accessor method in your model and the time format you want.

To format date and time easily, use `Carbon`

https://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: I  am retruning a row data not a `return $user->deleted_at->getTimestamp();`

Comment: What do you mean by row data ?

Comment: sorry gt it.Workingf just define in model `protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];`